# UI Asstes from Adobe Illustrator have low quality in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, unity-ui

So i have imported some UI assets to unity that i made in adobe illustrator, but they are really pixelated and low quality both in edit and play(simulator) mode. I also tried the same icon in higher resolutions but they all looked the same.

Thats how it looks in unity:

[image: thats how it looks in unity]

And here is the actual Icon i drew:

[image: no idea why it is so big]

Also these are the import settings for the icon:

[image]

Comment: are you sure your import settings are correct?

Comment: Yeah im pretty sure, the only thing i changed is the Texture type to Sprite(2D and UI)

Comment: how big is the icon? is it because its having to reduce the size down ?

Comment: I tried different sizes but they all looked the same, i had different sizes from 485x735 to 1351x2048.

Comment: was that big png you uploaded exactly what you imported or something else?

Comment: Yes, i tried the same icon in theses all sizes if thats what you mean. The 1351x2048 png was the same icon like on the picture but bigger and it looked exactly the same like the one on the picture.

Comment: Thats not what i asked. Was the png  exactly what you imported. Eg if i save that and import it you would expect me to get the same or was it another file or different in any way

Comment: Also i realized that not only UI element but also 3d models and some texts are pixelated .  Maybe there are some settings in the canvas or somewhere else that cause this issue?

Comment: Im sorry but i really dont understand what you mean, i saved the icon as a png in adobe illustrator, drag and dropped in the project window, changed the texture type to Sprite(2D and UI) and thats all i did.

Comment: so the answer was yes then

Comment: so, i saved the png, dropped it in the folder, changed to sprit/ui and https://imgur.com/a/E8E9Hhw looks fine to me.. its all you. perhaps it is because you are scaling it down? to make it say 1 unit in size? which you didnt answer? if you are dont scale it, change the pixels per unit

Comment: Have you tried generating the mip maps?